# Missing operand after '12' operator

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, datatable, dataset, datarow

i have a code like:

```
 DataRow[] ClassTime = DateTime.Tables["Table"].Select("ClassListingDate=" + Convert.ToDateTime(DDLClassDate.SelectedItem.Text) + "");
```

where DateTime is dataset which contain `ClassOffering` field which is in date type and contain a value as 5/15/2007 12:00:00 AM

```
DDLClassDate.SelectedItem.Text contains a value 5/15/2007 12:00:00 AM
```

after executing the above line it throw an exception `Missing operand after '12' operator`.
What type of exception it is? and what should i do to resolve this.Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `DataTabe.Select` for `DateTime` column, you should **enclose the value of `DateTime` in single quotes.**

```
 DataRow[] ClassTime = DateTime.Tables["Table"]
                               .Select("ClassListingDate='" +
                                Convert.ToDateTime(DDLClassDate.SelectedItem.Text) + "'");
```

*Not really sure why your `DataSet` is named as `DateTime`*

Consider the following example:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("ClassListingDate", typeof(DateTime));
DateTime dtNow = DateTime.Now.Date;
dt.Rows.Add(DateTime.Now.Date);
dt.Rows.Add(DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(1));
dt.Rows.Add(DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-1));
DataRow[] ClassTime =dt.Select("ClassListingDate='" + dtNow + "'");
                                                ^^^^          ^^^^^
                                                //Single quotes
```

The above would return a single row in `ClassTime`
[image]